# Delete Tag: 4096

Tags: feature-request, tags

A new tag called [4096](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/4096) has been recently created.

It is linked to only one question.

I personally don't see future questions using this tag and I don't see any value why the one linked question requires this tag.

Maybe this tag should be removed?

Comment: What's the syntax to get a tag link like that? Something like <tag></tag>?

Comment: @root45 `[tag:4096]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags been removed from the question, after a period of time the tag will be removed so long as it's not used again.