# Can misspelled tags be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just re-tagged a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83742/does-all-hardware-of-a-thinkpad-edge-e525-work) with a misspelled tag. From [these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1789/delete-tag-4096) [two](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2090/what-to-do-with-useless-new-tags) search results, it looks like tags are dropped after a period of inactivity. Can misspelled tags be deleted instead, so the error is less likely to recur?

The tags at issue here are 'hardware-recommendation' (correct) and 'hardware-reccommendation' (incorrect).

Comment: I [suggested merging](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2183/18612) that specific tag, but deleting it would be much better, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be merged with the proper tag, which has just happened in this case. In the future visit the correct tag's page, click Synonym, and suggest that the incorrect spelling of the tag be a synonym of the correctly spelled tag.

Comment: So there is no option to delete them. I was going to make a question about this since I found 2: "reccomendation" and "bandwith".